# C# and JSON having trouble parsing data

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I'm having a small bit of trouble.

I'm trying to let a user create an item. From there, I add the item to a list and serialize it.

```
ItemsList.Add(Items);
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ItemsList, Formatting.Indented);
File.AppendAllText(subPathJson + "/" + filename, json + Environment.NewLine);
```

`Items` Is a class that contains `Price`, `ID` and `Name`.

This works fine. However, with multiple items, I get a file which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Test",
    "price": 0.1
  }
]
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Test2",
    "price": 0.1
  }
]
```

However, I need my file to look like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Test",
    "price": 0.1
  },
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Lol",
    "price": 0.1
  }
]
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ItemsList` is being passed something called `Items`.. which is plural.  Since you don't provide the types for either variable, I'm going to guess that plurals indicates lists or arrays.. in which case `Itemslist` is a list of lists.. and the JSON is correct.   Flatten `ItemsList` before serializing it.

Comment: @SamAxe Sorry items is a class. Ill add that in too avoid confusion.

Comment: When you inspect `json` in the debugger, does it look like it should?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It may help you.

```
var invalidJson = "[{\"id\": 0,\"name\": \"Test\",\"price\": 0.1}][{\"id\": 0,\"name\": \"Test2\",\"price\": 0.1}]";
var json = invalidJson.Replace("][", ",");
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);

public class RootObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "price")]
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

You need to import [NewtonSoft.Json.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)